# How do i zoom in around specific locations in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, zooming

I have the image:

```
img = [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3;
       1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3;
       1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3;
       1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3;
       1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1;
       1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1;
       1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1];
```

Assuming I am interested in seeing finer details around the specific locations with:

```
Indx = [18; 47];
```

of coordinates:

```
rows = [4; 5] and cols = [3; 7]
```

I understand the `“zoom on/off”` allows one to zoom interactively by pressing the mouse button. Rather than this manual method however, is there a way to programmatically ask matlab to zoom around - say the `3x3 neighbourhood` of these locations (or more)? Whenever `‘imshow’` is called?

Please I need help/advice/suggestions on this. Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an "overkill", but you can use [`imwarp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html) function:

`imwarp` allows zooming with displacement (and more).

Assume:

- `(center_x, center_y)` is your point of interest.
- Output image (after zoom) is same as input image size.
- Point of interest should be at the center of the image after zoom.

I drawn a cross at the point of interest for testing.
I used `'peppers.png'` image for demonstration.

Here is my code sample:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
w = size(I, 2); %Image width
h = size(I, 1); %Image height

zoom = 4; %Zoom factor x4

%Point of interest.
center_x = w/2 - 80;
center_y = h/2 - 50;

%Draw center cross for testing (thickness is 2 pixels):
I(center_y-1:center_y, center_x-5:center_x+4, :) = 255;
I(center_y-5:center_y+4, center_x-1:center_x, :) = 255;

figure;imshow(I);

%Compute displacement:
x0 = w/2 - zoom*center_x;
y0 = h/2 - zoom*center_y;

%Build transformation matrix T.
T = [zoom   0      0; ...
     0      zoom   0; ...
     x0     y0     1];

tform = affine2d(T); %Needed by imwarp

%J = imwarp(I, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(I)), 'Interp', 'nearest'); %Select nearest interpolation.

%Apply transformation (dimensions of J will be the same as I).
J = imwarp(I, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(I)), 'Interp', 'cubic'); %Select cubic interpolation.
figure;imshow(J);
```

Input image (pay attention to the small cross):
[image]

Output image:
[image]

Comment: It works quite right and i'll try to adapt this to my situation. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a piece of [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/322422) which gives you the pixel location of the point you clicked. You can effectively use this code:

```
function [loc] = get_image_point (I)

figure('name','Doubleclick to set location');imshow(I);
[c r] = getpts(1);
loc = int32([c r]);
if size(loc)>1
    loc = [loc(1,1) loc(1,2)];
end
close all;
end
```

Having that pixel location, you can create a figure with the specified dimensions, let say you double click pixel position `(x,y)` in `image`. Then, you can simply say `figure('Position', [0 0 screenWidth screenHeight]), imshow(image(x-x1:x+x1, y-y1:y+y1))`. Make sure that `x+-x1` and `y+-y1` are within the range.